# NodeJS + SocketIO client side script

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm

So I have installed `socket.io` using the following command:

```
npm install --save socket.io
```

I have set up my server correctly, and I am now trying to set up my client. In order for my client to use the `socket.io` library I need to import the `socket.io` library. Traditionally, I would do it like so:

```
<script src="/path/to/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Except that all my `socket.io` stuff lives in `node_modules` on my server, which is not accessible from my views, who have the `public` folder as their root. How can I load `socket.io` in my client?

For others things in the past, I resolved to simply copy pasting inside the `public/js` folder, but I am not willing to this every time I install frontend stuff with `npm`. I have read online about things such as `Bower` and `Browserify` but the confusion was such that I decided to come here and ask for a straight answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can also load from CDN, although that hardly addresses your general issue with using npm modules on the client

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.5/socket.io.js"></script>
```

`Bower` is a separate package manager from `npm`, all it does is install modules into a specific folder, with a slant that modules it serves should be ready for inclusion on the client using script tags, there is no restriction on this though and it offers no features nor advantages over using `npm`, you'd still have to include scripts from a directory somewhere, what does it matter if its called `vendor` or `node_modules`?

The advantage you get with `npm` is a far larger set of modules, and with a larger set of modules comes a larger set of quality modules. However, modules on `npm` are expected to adhere to node's module system, which is basically commonJS, again there is no restriction on this, `npm` can and will host anything with a valid `package.json` file.

Tools like `Browserify` convert that module system into a format that can work in the browser, that's all they do.

If you’re unwilling to use a build system for your front-end then you must resort to loading from node_modules, a quick symlink into your `public` folder would suffice (although you'd likely want to be smarter about it). However, you’d have to go through the additional step of ensuring that the modules you want to use are ready for the browser, many modules within `npm` are targeted at `node` so they will not necessary work in the browser. Many modules will include a browser build or some sort of [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) so they will work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Socket.IO adds it's own route for the public part, and you should use it like:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

It should work like a charm :)